# Create additional context menu items via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, contextmenu

I need a context menu that has additional items based on a list.
Currently I'm doing this by looping through the list and adding the items like this:

```
var MyItemsList = new List<string>{
 "item1"
 "item2"
};
myContextMenu.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in MyItemsList)
{
    var menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.Header = item;
    menuItem.Click += (sender, args) => HandleItem(item);
    myContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
}
myContextMenu.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Static item"}); //etc, etc
```

How can I do this in XAML using bindings?

Comment: You can achieve what you need like this onky.  If you want,  you can place all the menu items and bind the visibility to properties so that each item is shown only when required.  Or else craete a user control with menus and add them dynamically to the context menu like what your're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put everything in a Collection, and set that Collection as the `ItemsSource` of your `ContextMenu`. You cannot set ItemsSource for only half of the MenuItems. Though you can use nested MenuItems for which you can set `ItemsSource`.

For example you can have :

- MenuItem1
- MenuItem2
- MenuItem3

  - SubMenu1
  - SubMenu2

MenuItem3 is having its `ItemsSource` set.